# Images not rendered when using h:outputStylesheet

Tags: css, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 Resource managing mechanism. Under /webapp/resources, I have 3 subfolders: images, scripts, styles. And in my template file myLayout.xhtml, I reference the style sheet as following

```
    <h:outputStylesheet name="styles/styles.css"/>
```

I put all my background images in my styles.css file as following:

```
    body {
           background: #fff url(../images/body_background.png) repeat -x;
    }

    #header {
           background: transparent url(../images/header_bg.png) no-repeat top right;
    }
```

All my page facelets reside under a sub folder /webapp/facelets while template files reside under /webapp/template. My facelet page.xhtml references template as following:

```
   <ui:compsition .... template="/template/myLayout.xhtml">
```

Then the page is properly layout except all the background images are missing. I've checked the log and found the following errors:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190: File not found: /javax.faces.resource/images/body_background.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190: File not found: /javax.faces.resource/images/header_bg.png
```

Then I change the url reference in css file from

```
    url(../images/body_background.png)
```

To 
        url(/i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference CSS image resources via `#{resource}` in EL so that it will print the proper JSF resource URL.

```css
body {
    background: #fff url(#{resource['images/body_background.png']}) repeat -x;
}

#header {
    background: transparent url(#{resource['images/header_bg.png']}) no-repeat top right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! If I want to add different versions of the resources, would this syntax still work? So now my image file would reside under /resources/default/1_0/images instead of /resources/images.

Comment: The library needs to be prefixed as in `#{resource['default:images/some.png']}`.

Comment: What about version? I know by default the highest version would be used. But what if now I have 2 versions 2_0, 1_0, obviously I don't want my 1_0 css refers to 2_0 images.

Comment: @BalusC any other solution ?, I can not change in all jquery ui files ?